# Controlling a GUI-only app though Python?

Tags: python, process

Let say I have an app called "G", that is GUI-only, i.e. I can't run it only from bash. While working with this program, various files are created that I'm interested in (e.g., think [Inkscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkscape)), but without any CLI support.

Is there some way I can control G only through Python, in order to automate various operations?

If G were CLI based, it would be easy, since I could simply launch from within Python the various commands to operate G.

But as G is not CLI, I assume I would need to launch G, to obtain the exact window location, and the very precisely place mouse clicks with Python on the various menu items to obtain what I want.
How can I do that in the best way? (Or is there an easier way to do that?)

(P.S. I'm mostly interested in Linux/Debian answers, but feel free to let me know about Windows too)